# Is there a programmatic way to hide the cursor in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I've set the editor to read only and it is read only but it is showing a cursor. I'd like to programmatically hide the cursor (not through a style unless programmatically).

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what suggested answers do, for visual comparison:

Here's what it looked like before:

[image]

adding:

```
editor.setOptions({readOnly: true, highlightActiveLine: false, highlightGutterLine: false});
```

as suggested by "a user", removes the gutter and line highlight, but the cursor is still there:

[image]

then adding the line:

```
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.element.style.display = "none"
```

as suggested by "daronwolff" removes the cursor:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can hide cursorLayer by using

```
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.element.style.display = "none"
```

Comment: To improve the UI  I would add this:

editor.setOptions({
    readOnly: true,
    highlightActiveLine: false,
    highlightGutterLine: false
})

Comment: @daronwolff Is that an alternative method? If it is you can post it as a separate answer

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to use `editor` (eg. React), you can simply hide inactive cursor using CSS:

```
.ace_hidden-cursors {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work when the editor isn't in focus

Answer (score 1):

Ace editor's cursor can be selected using `.ace_cursor`. Now, we can simply make it transparent or change the color.

```css
.ace_cursor {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```